# Как исправить ошибку в sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT *, date_start + (day_interval || ' day')::interval AS date_end FROM tariffs WHERE date_start<=date_end
```

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "date_end" does not exist

Как исправить?

Comment: У вас в таблице нет колонки с именем date_end. В части where вы можете обращаться только к колонкам, существующим в таблице. (т.к. часть where выполняется до начала выполнения части select) Если вам нужно сравнить с результатом вычисления выражения, которое вы назвали date_end в списке выборки, просто напишите в where само выражение.

Comment: вы хотите вычисленный столбец использовать в `where` условии что ли? не получится. where выполняется раньше чем инструкция селект, продублируйте выражение

Comment: правда, я не понимаю этого условия. вы прибавляете к date_start некое значение, потом пытаетесь проверить что результат больше чем тот же date_start. Это условие не будет выполнено только в случае если day_interval отрицателен, так что будет гораздо проще проверить `where day_interval>=0`

Comment: решено! спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, date_start + (day_interval || ' day')::interval AS date_end
FROM tariffs
WHERE date_start + (day_interval || ' day')::interval<current_timestamp
```

вот так решено.
Спасибо!